# Website with a grid of videos - 'talking heads'

Tags: php, html, flash, actionscript-3

I want to create a website displaying grid-sorted videos (interviews - movies showed in rows and columns). I want it to be 'a page with talking heads'. When users clicks on a video it starts playing.

I consider two ways:

1. The whole website made in flash - dynamically assigned number of videos per row/column and page, depending on the user's screen resolution.
2. Website made in php/html with help of JS and CSS - videos are displayed by YouTube player or other player e.g. JW Player - videos position depends on screen resolution.

What do you think - which way is better (consider performance too, please)?
Have you got any other ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: HTML5 Video could have better performance due to almost no resource consumption in idle while showing alt image.

Comment: I think you're looking for a chatroom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My opinion is that you have to use option 2. Creating HTML and CSS is much easier than Actionscript and as PimPee said Flash components are slower. I don't know any big commercial or entertainment site made entirely in Flash so my opinion is that you have to use PHP/HTML.
Also many Flash features could be replicated by using JS/Jquery which works faster and is easier to maintain. There is no point of creating sliders,dropdowns or other web behaviour functionalities in Flash when you can use Jquery. You should use Flash if you desire very sophisticated animation efects.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I have one more question - I want the layout of vides to be created dynamically - depending on screen resolution. Is that a good idea - isn't it gonna be too slow, especially on older computers?

Comment: You don't have problems concerning screen resolution because in CSS you could manipulate div width in procents. You could google Liquid Layouts in CSS.

Comment: But what with cases like 1920x1080 and 1024x768 - more videos could be dispalyed in one rowe - the screen is wider?

Comment: As I read you want to use grid view. You'll need thumbnail for each video. Usually the thumbnails are with fixed size in pixels. This means that if you use 8 thumbnails wide about 200 pixels on 1024x768 screen you'll have 4 thumbnails in a row and two columns; if the resolution is 1920x1080  you'll have to 8 thumbnails in a row. Other important question is the width of the div where the grid is placed.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. The number of thumbnails will be probably generated to exactly fit the whole screen (browser screen-size).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say number 2.

Since Flash is kind of slow and doesn't work on an ipad / iphone etc.

But that's just my opinion :)